# How to configure the user's terminal history in Synology DSM?

Tags: terminal, history, synology, command-history, synology-diskstation

The history is limited by `100` entries. In other Linux distros I can configure that in the `~/.bashrc` of my user. But in DSM I found no such a file. So, how to set the `$HISTSIZE` and the `$HISTFILESIZE` (permanently)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ nano ~/.profile
export HISTSIZE=1000000
export HISTFILESIZE=1000000
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
$ source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the file `/etc.defaults/.bashrc_profile` to keep the state of the variables constant.

If I remember it right, when the DSM system is rebooted the files in `/etc/` are replaced by files from `/etc.defaults/`.
Therefore, to maintain a persistent state, you need to change files in directory `/etc.defaults/`.